# If an nonnegative measurable function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1)$, then $\sum_{n \geq 0} 2^n m(\{x: f(x) \geq 2^n\})$ is finite

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $f$ is only defined on $(0,1)$. The converse statement is actually also correct, but I am only struggling with the given direction.

By considering $f_n = f\chi_{2^n \leq f < 2^{n + 1}}$, where $\chi$ is the indicator function, I could conclude by using monotone convergence theorem that $\sum_{n \geq 0} 2^n m(\{x: 2^n \leq f(x) < 2^{n + 1}\})$ is finite, but how do I go from here to the required sum?

Comment: The converse direction is actually where the M.C.T is needed.

Comment: Yeah, I did use monotone convergence theorem to prove the other direction, but how to prove the direction given?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but your method seems the same as what I mentioned in the question. Integrating the limit of $s$ gives the sum of $2^nm({x: 2^n\leq f(x) < 2^{n + 1}})$, which is smaller than the sum required in the question. How do we go from here to the conclusion?

Comment: @Riemann What you propose shows that $\sum 2^nm(\{2^n\leqslant f<2^{n+1}\}) < \infty$, which is exactly what OP claims to have already shown. This is not the question that is asked, namely, that $\sum 2^n m(\{f(x) \geqslant 2^n\}) <\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I found a solution and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having defined $$a_n = 2^{n}m(\{x\in X:2^n\le f(x)<2^{n+1}\}),$$ the desired sum is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k}a_{n+k}.$$ Since the terms are non-negative, we can rearrange to get $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{-k}\right)a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(2-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)a_n\le 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n.$$